# Regex positive lookahead with backreference

Tags: c#, .net, regex, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

I'm trying to build a very specific editor with syntax highlight.
I've made all the simple stuff with regular expressions wich was simple enough, but now I would like to add some advanced features also with regular expressions.

In this case I would like to know if a defined tag is used on any JumpTo command or not.
Example:

```
Define1,Command,Command
Define2,Command,Command,JumpTo4
Define3,Command,Command,JumpTo1
Define4,Command,Command
```

The objective here would be to find every *Define* (Definexxx) that is referenced by a *JumpTo* (one or many) may it be before or after the definition.
In another step I would also like to find any *Define* that is not referenced by any *JumpTo*.

I've tried the expression "**Define(?<tag>\d+)(?=JumpTo\k<tag>)**" for positive lookahead. I would expect that it would find "*Define1*" but it didn't (neither with nor without multiline option).

Is this possible to be done in one step Regex, or should I drop the idea and just consider a 2 step approach?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You were nearly there, just forgot a `.*`. And I've added a lookbehind assertion to also check before the current define:

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(
    @"Define(?<tag>\d+\b)       # Match Define<number>
    (?:                         # Match either...
     (?=.*JumpTo\k<tag>\b)      # if JumpTo<number> occurs somewhere ahead 
    |                           # or...
     (?<=JumpTo\k<tag>\b.*)     # if JumpTo<number> occurs somewhere before 
    )                           # End of alternation", 
    RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

I've added `\b` word boundary anchors to ensure that we're always matching the entire number (this gets important if we reach `Define10` and above).

Also, please note the use of the `Singleline` option. This is what you want, not `Multiline` which refers to how `^` and `$` match.

Comment: Shouldn't "Define(?<tag>\d+\b)" instead be "Define(?<tag>\d+)\b"?
In the first expression "\b" will be included in the <tag> so that "(?=.*JumpTo\k<tag>\b)" will actually match "Jump<tag>\b\b"... I'm I right?

Comment: @Suriv, `\b` is a zero-width assertion; it doesn't matter whether it's inside the group or outside because it doesn't consume any characters.  I think it looks neater inside.